# How can I keep same function names meant for different things in their own scope (It may not be the right word)?

Tags: javascript

I have created two different independent scripts to update two different canvas. The problem is that some of the function names in both the scripts are same. This is going to result in conflicts.

I could combine them together to form a big script but that will soon become messy if I try to add more functionality. Similarly, naming every function differently will be tedious and error prone.

Is there some way, I can keep the scripts with same function names on a single page without any conflict?

Here is my code:

```
var DropEffect = {

  var dropSize, speed;

  var createDrops = function () {
     var canvas = document.getElementById("drop");
     ....
  };
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
 Unexpected token name «dropSize», expected punc «:»
```

Comment: name space them - `LibA.updateCanvas()` & `LibB.updateCanvas()`. can do this by placing the functions in objects `LibA = { updateCanvas: function() { } } //etc.`

Comment: IIFE's are common for fully self contained "chunks" `;(function() { ... code goes here ... })();`

Comment: Sorry @hackerrdave I don't understand. :) How do I modify the code so that I can append the `LibA` and `LibB` or other names without breaking the functionality.

Comment: @hackerrdave Your updated comment helps a lot. Let me try that. :)

Comment: give some dummy parameters  for eg: function a(a,b)  , function a(a,b,c), if you did like this , you wont get conflict...

Comment: @hackerrdave It is giving me errors. I am adding part of my code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it like this:

File 1:

```
var nm1 = {

myFunction: function(){

}

}
```

File 2:

```
var nm2 = {

myFunction: function(){

}

}
```

Now, whenever you want to access, use *nm1.myFunction() or nm2.myFunction()*;

**In general such kind of objects are called namespaces**.

After you modified question,

```
var DropEffect = {

  var dropSize, speed;

  var createDrops = function () {
     var canvas = document.getElementById("drop");
     ....
  };
}
```

This is not correct. You are creating variables inside an object (namespace).Objects just understand key-value pairs. Better do it like this,

```
var DropEffect = {

  dropSize : "",
  speed : "",
  createDrops : function () {
     var canvas = document.getElementById("drop");
     ....
  };
}
```

and now use it as: **DropEffect.dropSize** etc.

Comment: I also have some variable inside the namespace which keeps giving me errors. I have updated my question. :)

Comment: I modified my answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap code in IIFE's like this:

```
(function(){

   var theFunction = function(){

      console.log('foo');

   };

   theFunction();

}());

(function(){

   var theFunction = function(){

      console.log('bar');

   };

   theFunction();

}());
```